# How to get voice input from bluetooth headset and get battery left info on ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, microphone

The device I am using is boat 511v2 TWP which has Bluetooth v5.0 connectivity and my computer runs Ubuntu 20.04 & Windows 10 May 2020. The issue I am facing is that I cant get HSP/HFP profile to work on ubuntu as a result I am not able to get voice input from my headset. Whereas on windows it works flawlessly. How can I fix this? Also is there any way to get battery left information as we get on windows and android on Ubuntu?